# Android V7 Support FrameLayout does not scale properly

Tags: android, android-layout

Android layouts seem to have a tendency to refuse me, I can only hope I am not the only one who finds them ridiculous.

I have basically designed my interfaces using RelativeLayouts (which seem to do exactly what they are told) but I find, that they do not scale at all. The only way I can see that design scale is using plenty of dimens.xml files to supply width values for all mayor input widgets for all sorts of screen sizes. That is not exactly a seamless solution.

So I started experimenting with support.v7.GridLayout. 
To me it looks like the design is not very robust, rather erratic - I guess like in most cases it is my fault but I have worked out exactly when it fails. 
My basic design looks like this and it works as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dip"
    app:columnCount="4"
    app:rowCount="4"
    >

<TextView
    style="@style/StdText"
    android:id="@+id/test_tvid_1"
    android:text="@string/txt_dummy"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    app:layout_column="0"
    app:layout_row="0"
    app:layout_columnSpan="4"
    android:background="#7F0000"
    />


<TextView
    style="@style/StdText"
    android:id="@+id/test_tvid_2"
    android:text="@string/txt_dummy"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    app:layout_column="0"
    app:layout_row="1"
    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:background="#7F0000"
    />

<TextView
    style="@style/StdText"
    android:id="@+id/test_tvid_2_1"
    android:text="@string/txt_dummy"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    app:layout_column="1"
    app:layout_row="1"
    app:layout_columnSpan="2"
    android:background="#007F00"
    />

<TextView
    style="@style/StdText"
    android:id="@+id/test_tvid_3"
    android:text="@string/txt_dummy"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    app:layout_column="1"
    app:layout_row="2"
    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:background="#007F00"
    />
<TextView
    style="@style/StdText"
    android:id="@+id/test_tvid_4"
    android:text="@string/txt_dummy"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    app:layout_column="2"
    app:layout_row="2"
    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:background="#00007F"
    />
<TextView
    style="@style/StdText"
    android:id="@+id/test_tvid_5"
    android:text="@string/txt_dummy"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    app:layout_column="3"
    app:layout_row="2"
    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:background="#7f007f"
    />

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

[Image of the Layout](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/xq90/538/i5dj1c.png)

All I have to do to destroy the layout is go to the TextView No. 3 id:test_tvid_2_1 and change the app:layout_columnSpan to 3, which is a valid size and within the given column count of 4. 
What happens, is that the layout suddenly expands beyond the screen, so that column 4 (colIdx 3) is not completely on screen any more and the text actually disappears. This happens on a device as well as in the AndroidStudio layout designer.
This is only the most simple way to trigger that sort of behavior. It actually happens whenever I add more 'complicated' rows.. Can anyone please either point out my mistake ? 
Cheers Thomas

Comment: Now Post Image. ... :)

Comment: Don't say "Unfortunately I have to wait to get 10 reputation to post the image of the layout ;)" you can upload image somewhere else and put a link here

Comment: Yes you are right and nagging is probably not a good way to get reputation anyway.. The picture is on its way..